# Cannot update the second dateRangeInput if I manually change the first dateRangeInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an example code below showing two `dateRangeInput`. The selected dates of the second `dateRangeInput` is dependent on the first `dateRangeInput`. Here is the same version on the Shinyapps.io (https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/shiny_daterange/).

The strange behavior I would like to demonstrate is if I manually changed the date values in the first `dateRangeInput`, the second `dateRangeInput` becomes NA.

For example, if I selected the date in the first `dateRangeInput`, the app can update the second `dateRangeInput` successfully.

[image]

[image]

However, if I manually remove the date values in the input box of the first `dateRangeInput`, and then type in the new date value, the date values in the second `dateRangeInput` becomes `NA`.

[image]

[image]

It seems like a non-desired behavior as I expect these two selection methods (using calendar or manually change it) should be the same. Please let me know if I can fix this behavior.

```
library(shiny)

# Create the ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput(inputId = "date_input1", label = "Select Date Range 1",
                 start = "2000-01-01", end = "2019-12-31",
                 min = "2000-01-01", max = "2019-12-31"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "date_output1"),
  dateRangeInput(inputId = "date_input2", label = "Select Date Range 1",
                 start = "2000-01-01", end = "2019-12-31",
                 min = "2000-01-01", max = "2019-12-31"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "date_output2")
)

# Create the server
server <- function(session = session, input = input, output = output){
  # Update the date selection in date_input2
  observe({
    updateDateRangeInput(session = session, inputId = "date_input2", label = "Select Date Range 1",
                    start = input$date_input1[[1]], end = input$date_input1[[2]],
                    min = "2000-01-01", max = "2019-12-31")
  })
  
  # Print the selected date
  output$date_output1 <- renderText({
    paste(input$date_input1[[1]], input$date_input1[[2]], sep = " - ")
  })
  
  output$date_output2 <- renderText({
    paste(input$date_input2[[1]], input$date_input2[[2]], sep = " - ")
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line before the updateDateRangeInput call

```
req(input$date_input1[[1]],input$date_input1[[2]])
```

The problem is that when you are editing by hand, for a time the date is not properly formed and is permanently breaking the second date input for some reason. The `req()` call just insists that there are proper values in there before updating the second date input.